# Soundcloud API with SoundManager doesn't return peakData

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am using SoundManager2 to stream music from SoundCloud. However, it is not returning to me the peakData (or WaveformData or EQData).

I have tried using both SoundManager2 directly and also the SoundCloud API Wrapper, with the same result.

I would like the peakData data in order to create visualisations. I cannot use a plain HTML5 Audio API player as I require other functions returned by SoundManager (or Soundcloud API wrapper).

The track plays, but soundManager.features returns that peakData is false and the peak data returns and array of '0'.

Code is as follows, and there is a private CodePen of a simplified set up here:
[SoundCloud Test](http://codepen.io/team/craftedbygc/pen/JdbwKj?editors=001)

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'b5ec05bfa8844fff9b84362925f46745'
});

var soundcloud_track;
SC.get('/tracks/202764956', {}, function(track){
    soundcloud_track = track.stream_url+'?client_id=b5ec05bfa8844fff9b84362925f46745';

    streamTrack();
});

function streamTrack(){
    soundManager.setup = {
        preferFlash: true,
    }

    soundManager.flash9Options = {
        usePeakData: true,     // enable left/right channel peak (level) data
        useWaveformData: true, // enable sound spectrum (raw waveform data) - WARNING: May set CPUs on fire.
        useEQData: true,       // enable sound EQ (frequency spectrum data) - WARNING: Also CPU-intensive.
    }

    var sound = soundManager.createSound({
        url: soundcloud_track,
        autoPlay: true,
        onplay: function(){
            console.log(soundManager.features);
        },
        whileplaying: function(){
            console.log(sound.peakData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: tell me if this answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want the data:**

Soundcloud starts to give the peakdata directly. If you still get a PNG:

To get it:

- retrieve the waveform PNG
- change the extension to .json
- change w1 to wis

in your case:

https://w1.sndcdn.com/Oz5FJMJhr8Ho_m.png
become
https://wis.sndcdn.com/Oz5FJMJhr8Ho_m.json

you Get It!

---

**if you also want to draw it:**

http://waveformjs.org/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am looking for the peakData which is a realtime value returned by SoundManager2, and not the waveform itself from Soundcloud. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a bug or something, I have 0 values too.

Maybe it comes from the fact this parameters needs **flash9+**.

[image: zero]

What about using the last answer so you get the complete waveform data and you just take the data you neeed at a certain time?

It's better than making a call everytime you need the peak data; and it's fully compatible.

Comment: Thanks. It may come to that. But ideally I'd like to have a bit more analysis of the sound than the waveform produces. I'll keep it in mind as a last resort though :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to get the peak-data from the image file and is prepared to perform that action on the server side, this might help.

A while ago I created a PHP script that retrieves the PNG image with the waveform data, scans it for the peaks and returns it as a JSON object.

I will provide my code as is, you need the code in the `mLoad` function, and the peaks are in `$tmpPeaks`

(`$tmpReturnO` is just an object that I use to return data and or errors and stuff, ignore it.)

You can see an the [peakdata waveform code in action here](http://moire.noviomagiers.nl/prutsonic/).

The file is untouched so you have to pull out what you need, it should be self explanatory, for further info see the [complete thread on github](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/issues/16#issuecomment-82606468).

```
<?php

/**
 * waveformClass 
 * retrieves the waveform image from soundcloud
 * Analyses it for peakdata and returns those peaks in an array or binary string
 */

class waveformClass extends baseClass {

    private $pParentO;      

    public $pURL = '';
    public $pPeakData = '';

    public function __construct(moireClass &$parentOIn) {
        parent::mInit();
        $this->pParentO = $parentOIn;
    }

   /** 
    * mLoad, load the wavefile from remote URL
    * 
    * @param $URLIn string URI of the png image
    * @param $doBinary boolean when true, instead of an array, 
    * a binary bytestring consisting of 1800 bytes will be returned 
    * For demonstration purpose - to show how to shave off datatraffic
    * on peakdata array loading vs loading of a png image
    * 
    * @return result an array with the peak-heights or a binary string
    */

    public function mLoad($URLIn, $doBinary = false) {

        $tmpBinaryString = "";
        $tmpReturnO = $this->_mGetReturnObject();

        $width = 1800;
        $height = 280;

        $srcimage = imagecreatefrompng($URLIn);

        imageAlphaBlending($srcimage, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($srcimage, true);

        $tmpPeaks =  array(); 

        for ($x=0;  $x<1800; $x++) { // the width of the image is 1800
            for ($y=0; $y<140; $y++) { // the image is symmetrical, so we only take (140 pixels) the half of the height (of 280 pixels)

                $rgb = imagecolorat($srcimage, $x, $y);

                $colors = imagecolorsforindex($srcimage, $rgb);

                if ($colors['alpha'] == 127) {
                    break;
                }               
            }
            $tmpPeaks[] = 140-$y;
        }


        if ($doBinary) {
            $tmpBinaryString = call_user_func_array("pack", array_merge(array("C*"), $tmpPeaks));

            $tmpReturnO->mOk($tmpBinaryString);
        } else {
            $tmpReturnO->mOk($tmpPeaks);
        }

        return $tmpReturnO->mGetReturnRecord();

    }
}
?>
```